Why does the coefficient lose significance when using IV independent variable and also including district fixed effects?
I am trying to examine the effect of a 2018 flood shock on labor force participation of male and female. However, the flood could not only be attributed to heavy rainfall but to other factors like poor storage capacity of reservoirs, opening of dam gates. So, the flood is not entirely exogenous. Hence, I first regressed 99th percentile monsoon rainfall (calculated for each monsoon month over 1989-2018) on flood damage scores (used PCA to construct damage index for each district using districtwise damage information like crop area affected, fish farms affected, causalities etc.) using district fixed effects and year fixed effects. Next, I am using the predicted values from this regression as main independent variable for the regression of flood shock on labor force participation. However, the coefficient becomes statistically insignificant when I am taking district fixed effects. It remains statistically significant in absence of district fixed effects. Can anyone please tell me why is this happening? How can I address this issue?
NOTE: The first regression is based on daily rainfall data for each district during 1989-2018 which is kind of panel But in the second regression, the individual and household level data is repeated cross-section and is available in four quarters of each year during 2017-2019.

First, I wouldn't emphasize significant vs. not significant. Andrew Gelman wrote a paper on this titled "The difference between 'significant' and 'not significant' is not, itself, statistically significant" explaining this.
Second, the change in the parameter estimates and their standard errors for flood shock happen because controlling for district removes some of the effect. This can happen whenever two (or more) independent variables are not orthogonal. So, flood shock is related to district.
Controlling for the effect of other variables is one of he main reasons to do multiple rather than simple regression.
Finally, although it's not your question, I'm wondering how you are dealing with the repeated data. Are you just looking at one time point? If not, then you have to deal with the fact that you will violate the assumption of independent errors.

Thank you for your response and raising an important issue in your comment. Could you please explain about looking at one time point? Because I am comparing the outcome of a household before and after the flood shock, I have to look at more than one time point. In that regard, won't district fixed effect help since each district is repeated in each round of survey?

But you said you have data on individual households.  Can you edit your question t include your model either as an equation or, if you can't do that, as R code or whatever?
